# Growable buffer for plain C

Tags: c, open-source, buffer

I need an open-source (preferably MIT-licensed) light-weight growable buffer implemented in plain C (preferably also compileable as C++).

I need API equivalent to following (pseudo-code):

- `void set_allocator(buffer * buf, allocator_Fn fn);`
- `void push_bytes(buffer * buf, const char * bytes, size_t len);`
- `size_t get_length(buffer * buf);`
- `void overwrite_autogrow(buffer * buf, size_t offset, const char * bytes, size_t len);`
- `const char * to_string(buffer * buf);`

Implementation should be clean and self-contained.

The `overwrite_autogrow` writes `len` of `bytes` to given offset while growing buffer as needed (as `push_bytes` does).

Ability to set allocator is optional, but preferable to have.

Does somebody know anything close to what I want?

Or, at least, any implementations worth looking at while implementing my own?

Comment: we're talking about C, the eternal haven of wheel-(re)-inventors; if the framework you're using doesn't provide the functionality, roll your own implementation

Comment: I've updated my answer. Which opensource implementation should I look at when writing my own growing buffer? :-)

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by `pollute your code with macros` ? Anything portable is going to work around subtle differences between malloc(), realloc() and memcpy(), depending on the platform, especially if it provides a logging callback. You, yourself noted that you would like to be able to specify the allocator.

Comment: Well, there is a difference between excessive pollution and unavoidable usage. :-) I'll remove that phase — "clean and self-contained" is sufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**VPOOL** (BSD License)

http://www.bsdua.org/libbsdua.html#vpool

> Vpool is an auto-resizeable buffer
>   (dynamic array). Using it, you don't
>   need to care about memory allocation,
>   boundary checking, pointer
>   manipulations and etc.

Comment: Thanks! That is almost what I want (it has some extra features and has no support for custom allocators — but that is fixable).

Answer (score 0):

http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/stable/glib-Arrays.html

not sure if it implements overwrite_autogrow though, as I don't know what you mean by this. You want to manually set a capacity? If so g_array_set_size.

However, the licence may be a problem, but you should be able to use it as LGPL. I don't know if that's comaptible with MIT or not.

Comment: I've updated my question to explain overwrite_autogrow.
I'm trying to avoid [L]GPL as much as I can, but I'll take it if I wouldn't find anything better. Thanks!